# Android: get raw bitmap data from touch events

Tags: android, events, bitmap, touch-event

Is there a possibility to get an array/bitmap with the raw data of the touched spots on an Android touch display? (See illustration)
[image: Illustration of desired touch information]

So far I only know the commands event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getSize, ...

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You want to get the raw pixels of the area of the bitmap touched?

Comment: Exactly. For example a bit array with 1280 x 720 flags, which indicates, if the correspondent pixel on the display is touched. Or something like this...

Comment: Try playing with "inputs" in the "developer options" on your device. Playing with the "show touches" option should demonstrate that what you want to do is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this in user space. The touch input driver, part of the kernel, is responsible for taking the 'bitmap' and converting it into different points. In order to accomplish what you are trying to achieve, you need to build a new android kernel whose touch drivers work differently. These new drivers would have to provide an API for interacting with the unprocessed data.