# Android - How to get raw touch screen data?

Tags: android, touch-event

How to get an array/bitmap data from android touch screen?
(the shape and area of the touch).
Same question as this one [Android: get raw bitmap data from touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403604/android-get-raw-bitmap-data-from-touch-event), but this is very old.
The data is processed in the kernel, is there any way I can get it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible since your touchscreen only recognizes a few points. For example, try using any kind of a Paint app. You will see that your whole finger won't get noticed if you put it on the screen. Only a few dots will be painted.

Also notice that some phones don't support multi touches. I would recommend you to rethink about your app design. Maybe you could try let the user draw something to achieve a result you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I mean that I want the raw touch data before it is converted into the points (that you mentioned). Actually, I want the data for research purpose not for app design.

Comment: Then your only option is tweaking the kernel driver or try using developer options.

Comment: What do you mean by developer options? Do you mean developer options in android phones (in settings)? I have checked it, but there is no such feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's what I ment. Check cursor location.